# F# String to numeric parse. Incomplete pattern matches on this expression

Tags: f#, tryparse

Error creating command line menu in F#. function should essentially take a char(string) convert to num and run the = code.

```
Module Main = 
    let rec commandmenu() = 
       printfn "Select a command"
       printfn "1. Word count Command - Word count"
       printfn "2. Word count Command help"
       printfn "3. Touch Command - Touch file"
       printfn "4. Touch Command help"
       printfn "5. Version"
       printfn "6. Quit"
       printfn "--------------------------------"
       printfn "Select option (Eg '1','5') "


       let optionselect = Console.ReadLine()
       match System.Int32.TryParse optionselect with
       | (true, number) when number = 1
                        -> wordcount()
                          // printf"Press any key to continue"
       | (true, number) when number = 2
                        -> wordcounthelp()

       | (true, number) when number = 3
                        -> touch()

       | (true, number) when number = 4
                        -> touchhelp()

       | (true, number) when number = 5
                        -> version()
       | (true, number) when number = 6
                        -> 0   //Exit code
```

I don't expect my options to function correctly as they haven't been correctly coded yet but this error is preventing a build altogether. Have of course included open System.

Comment: FYI you can match on numeric literals directly e.g. `| (true, 1) -> wordcount()`. You aren't handling other numbers, or the case where the boolean is `false`.

Comment: Did you try "module" instead of what you show here ("Module")?

Comment: Assuming the `Module` with a capital M is a typo, http://www.ideone.com/zUXIdO I had to add dummy functions but this compiles fine. What error do you have *exactly* ?

Comment: YOu could use a command line library like Argu or something else.

Answer (score 4):

An incomplete pattern match error indicates that all the possibilities of the match expression (`System.Int32.TryParse optionselect`) are not accounted for. There are two big reasons in this particular case.

1. There is no accounting for the possibility of TryParse yielding a false as the first value of the returned tuple.
2. Since the second value of the returned tuple is an Int32, you would have to account for all the other possible values an Int32 can have, either explicitly or by default (with a wildcard for the Int32 value).

I don't know what each of the various functions you are invoking do, but it might be enough to add a wildcard pattern as the fall through case and simply recursively call `commandmenu`.

Adding...

```
       | _ -> commandmenu ()
```

... might be enough.

On a side note: you don't need the guard clauses using `when` for each of the cases. Just place the actual value, 1,2, etc. in place of the `number` binding. E.G.

```
| (true, 1) -> wordcount()
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you, it was the other possibilities not being addressed that that caused the issue, also the the code reduction you recommended made my code cleaner, thanks again. Slight issue with my exit option, but that's unrelated to my question. Perfectly explained answer.

Comment: @user4999318 in this case you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously belong in the category of homework, so it makes sense to address the coding issues rather than the specific problem. That problem will go away as the coding issues are fixed, so indirectly I'll be addressing the specific issue.

There is duplicated code in the sample. Duplicated code is what we call a code smell, and frequently indicates that something is wrong. The duplicated code looks like this.

```
| (true, number) when number = <<some number>>
```

In this case the duplication is a result of trying to do two tasks simultaneously, rather than breaking up the logic into smaller pieces. The first step should be to convert a string into a number. For this we can simply create a function.

```
let tryParse s =
    match Int32.TryParse s with
    | true, i -> Some i
    | false, _ -> None
```

The outcome of this is `Some n` or `None`. We can then either match on these two, and in the branch for `Some n` go on with a match simply on `n`. A possibly better alternative in this case is to match on `Some 1`, `Some 2` etc, which makes it possible to have a common wildcard match (the `_`) for both `Some n` and `None` when `n` is a number we're not interested in. Like this.

```
let optionselect = Console.ReadLine()
match tryParse optionselect with
| Some 1 -> something1 ()
| Some 2 -> something2 ()
| _ -> somethingOther () // another number, or not parsable
```

If you'd like to handle that possible other number, whatever it is, you'd match on `Some n` and on `None` at the end instead of just on the wildcard.